# Is there a machine learning algorithm that can be trained with pairs of integer sets?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, sparse

Like, the training set is composed of positive examples (s1, s2) where s1 is an integer set and s2 another integer set. s1 and s2 may have different cardinality. Negative examples are similar: pairs (s3, s4) of integer sets.

The biggest integer in any set is known in advance and the same for all sets (s1, s2, ...). All integers are positive.

Positive examples will be extracted from a dataset.

Out of the dataset for positive examples, negative examples will be constructed by some randomization that will avoid producing any of the known positive examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the main problem is to actually extract features from the input data. Once you encode your pairs of sets as vectors, you can use almost any algorithm you want, but it seems it would be wise to first perform some kind of dimensionality reduction, feature selection or use a classifier that has these built-in, like Lasso-regularized logistic regression.

The most obvious approach is to use [Bag of Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) approach with integers as words (specifically it seems appropriate to encode both sets separately and then concatenate their term-frequency matrices).

Of course you'll have to accept either that you give the possible integer range at the start or that some integers don't get encoded.

If you want some practice for BoW model, I'd recommend trying [this hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stitch-the-torn-wiki). For example, you can solve it using scikit learn - it's documentation contains tutorial on [Working With Text Data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).